# How to import module and display on view in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

[image]

I am trying to load my first view in angular. But I make a project in modular fashion to learn good coding style.

I will show how I make a directory to create a module

Or look at full image here...

[image]

I write this on my **index.html** page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="lib/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-ui-router.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body >
     <div ng-app="firstApp">
         <div ui-view="app"></div>
     </div>


</body>

</html>
```

in **app.js**

```
var app= angular.module('firstApp',['ui.router']);
```

in controller **firstcontroller.js** file I write this

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('firstApp')
        .controller('firstcont', firstcont);

    firstcont.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function firstcont($scope) {
        $scope.clickEvent=function(){
            alert('---')
        }
    }

})();
```

on **router.js** file I write this

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('firstApp.firstdir').config(Routes);


    Routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
    function Routes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        // Default
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');
        // Application
        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '/app',
                views:{
                    app: { templateUrl: 'firstdir/templates/firstpage.html' }
                },
                controller:"firstcont"

            });
    }

})();
```

in **module.js** file I write this

```
(function() {
    'use strict',

        angular.module('firstApp.firstdir', [
            'ui.router',
        ]);

})();
```

on template.html I write this

```
<div ng-controller="firstcont">
    <h1>First page</h1>
    <button ng-click="clickEvent()"> go to second page</button>
</div>
```

I don't know why it doesn't display first view. Actually, I am not able to make plunker, because there is no way to make directory?

```
angular.js:78 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module firstApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module firstApp.firstdir due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'firstApp.firstdir' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$injector/nomod?p0=firstApp.firstdir
    at file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:78:12
    at file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:1668:17
    at ensure (file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:1592:38)
    at module (file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:1666:14)
    at file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:3852:22
    at forEach (file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:325:18)
    at loadModules (file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:3846:5)
    at file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:3853:40
    at forEach (file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:325:18)
    at loadModules (file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:3846:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$injector/modulerr?p0=firstApp.firstdir&…%3A%2FUsers%2Fnksharma%2FDesktop%2FAngularjs%2Flib%2Fangular.js%3A3846%3A5)
    at file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:78:12
    at file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:3880:15
    at forEach (file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:325:18)
    at loadModules (file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:3846:5)
    at file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:3853:40
    at forEach (file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:325:18)
    at loadModules (file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:3846:5)
    at createInjector (file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:3786:11)
    at doBootstrap (file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:1435:20)
    at bootstrap (file:///C:/Users/nksharma/Desktop/Angularjs/lib/angular.js:1450:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$injector/modulerr?p0=firstApp&p1=Error%…3A%2FUsers%2Fnksharma%2FDesktop%2FAngularjs%2Flib%2Fangular.js%3A1450%3A12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First include the js files (the module declaration always come first, and first submodules)

```
<!-- The order here is very important -->
<script src="js/module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/router.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/firstcontroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Declare your 'firstcont' as a firstApp.firstDir controller:

```
var firstDir = angular.module('firstApp.firstdir');
...
firstDir.controller('firstcont', firstcont);
```

Put your submodule as a dependece of your firstApp module:

```
//Remember firstApp.firstdir must be already declared :)
var app= angular.module('firstApp',['firstApp.firstdir', 'ui.router']);
```

UPDATE:
Here's the code example http://goo.gl/xxvIvB (to run click in preview)

Comment: @user944513 I've update with the link to the example :)

Comment: sir I have one Question why we use this   app: { templateUrl: 'js/firstdir/templates/firstpage.html' } ..intead of   app: { templateUrl: 'firstdir/templates/firstpage.html' } or   app: { templateUrl: '/templates/firstpage.html' }

Comment: Because the reference used is based on your currently index.html. The index file is located under the 'root' dir, so this is your baseurl reference.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your routes in another module: firstApp.firstdir.
To import the module, use the following syntax:

```
var app= angular.module('firstApp',['firstApp.firstdir']);
```

You don't need to import ui.router, because its imported from firstApp.firstdir.

Comment: not working I am getting this error after using user code ..Please check update

Comment: could you please tell me your id so that I will send my simple code

Comment: could you please give better solution ?

Comment: could I use this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/try_angularjs_online.php for sharing the code ?

Comment: Please do you have any solution ?>

Comment: Did you forget to include the script tag for firstApp.firstdir?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68810/discussion-between-user944513-and-pixelbits).